# Problem with an Arduino controlling a CNC

Tags: arduino-uno

My Arduino with CNC shield has a port on my Mac listed as  "/dev/cu.usbmodem 1411".  I want the CNCjs software to use the same port but this software says the port is "/dev/tty.usbmodem1411".  Is this going to cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

TTY is correct. CU is the receive component of the UART/Serial Port and TTY is the send component. They are referencing the same port as long as the part after the "." is the same.  TTY is what is typically used by applications accessing the serial port.  You can read more here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/tips-and-tricks